# Not-disabled Read-only checkbox in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a form on it. I would like to make all the checkboxes and radio buttons on the page read-only (non-editable) without making them have the "disabled" appearance. I just want to prevent the user from easily changing the value of the checkbox. How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably the cleanest way to do it:

```
var deactivator = function(event){ event.preventDefault(); };

$(':radio, :checkbox').click(deactivator);
```

And to re-enable them:

```
$(':radio, :checkbox').unbind('click',deactivator);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `preventDefault` in the click event handler for all checkboxes and radio buttons:

```
$(":checkbox, :radio").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sTATS/1/).

Answer (score 0):

If you requirement is only to enable or disable the ability to interact with a specific check box, while not preventing posting of the element another solution is :

```
if (interaction === true){
   $('#elID').click(false);
} else {
   $('#elID').unbind('click');
}
```